# Understanding fitness function

Tags: cryptography, genetic-algorithm, equation, block-cipher

I am working with use of genetic algorithm to break transposition cipher. So in this work I have come across to a paper named *[Breaking Transposition Cipher with Genetic Algorithm](http://www.ee.ktu.lt/journal/2007/7/18_ISSN_1392-1215_Breaking%20Transposition%20Cipher%20with%20Genetic%20Algorithm.pdf) by R. Toemeh & S. Arumugam*.

In this paper they have used a fitness function. But i can not understand it completely. I can not understand the function of β and γ in the equation.

Can anyone please explain the fitness function please? Here is the picture of the fitness function:

[image: fitness function of Toemeh & Arumugam algorithm]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  weights β and γ can  be  varied  to  allow  more  or  less 
emphasis on particular statistics (they're determined "experimentally").

`Kb(i, j)` and `Kt(i, j, k)` are the known language bigram and trigram statistics. E.g. for English language you have (bigrams):

[image: heat map with frequency distribution of all 26 x 26 bigrams]

(further details in [The frequency of bigrams in an English corpus](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2014/09/26/bigrams.html))

`Db(i, j)` and `Dt(i, j ,k)` are the bigram and trigram statistics of 
the  message  decrypted  with  key `k`.

In *[A Generic Genetic Algorithm to Automate an Attack on Classical Ciphers](http://research.ijcaonline.org/volume64/number12/pxc3885588.pdf) by Anukriti Dureha and Arashdeep Kaur* there are some reference values of β and γ (and α since they use an extended form of the above equation) and three types of ciphers.

---

Some further details about β and γ.

They're weights that remain constant during the evolution. They should be tuned experimentally ("optimal" values depends on the target languages and the cipher algorithms).

Offline parameter tuning is the way to go, i.e.:

- simple parameter sweep (try everything)
- [meta-GA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-optimization)
- [racing strategy](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.48.954)

Comment: Ok, but what are β and γ for? Do they change? After all, OP stated *"I can not understand the function of β and γ in the equation."*

Comment: @ArtjomB. They're "simple" weights that remain constant during a run of the evolution.  They should be tuned experimentally ("optimal" values depends on the target languages and the cipher algorithms).